# Laravel - Ajuda com Autenticação

Tags: laravel, api, autenticação

Estou utilizando o Laravel 5.3 e estou tendo uma dor de cabeça com a Autenticação.
Estou usando o make:auth. Até então é simples, mas vejamos o cenário abaixo.

No meu projeto, quando faço o login eu envio o email e senha para a API(Node) que me retorna um token caso o usuário exista. Até aqui está ok. Com o token e os dados do usuário retornados eu gostaria de usar o make:Auth do Laravel para realizar o login. Justamente pra continuar utilizando o Auth::user(), Auth::check() e etc e manter a estrutura que o Laravel já me fornece.

Fiz algumas pesquisas e não achei muita coisa sobre esse assunto.

Alguém sabe se tem como fazer? Se sim, pode me dar um exemplo?
Ou quem sabe eu possa criar um Custom Authentication que consiga continuar usando Auth::user(), Auth::check() e etc? Se alguém souber aceito exemplos também. :)

**UPDATE**

**O Projeto:**

Estou usando a plataforma Heroku (https://www.heroku.com/) onde está meu Web Service (Node) e o Database (Mongo), e estou usando o Laravel para meu Website.

**O que quero fazer:**

Quando faço o login, minha ApiController envia com cUrl uma requisição para o WebService passando o email e a senha do usuário. O WebService vai fazer a verificação, caso não exista o usuário ele retorna null e caso exista um usuário ele me retorna um token com os dados do usuário. O que fazer com o token e os dados do usuário? Pelo que sei, preciso guardar em uma Sessão. Se eu usar Session para guardar os dados eu não consigo por exemplo retornar o usuário usando Auth::user() ou caso eu queira checar não posso usar Auth:check().

Daí minha dúvida. Existe alguma maneira de guardar o token e dados do usuário e continuar usando o Auth::user(), Auth::check() e etc?

Esses dois links abaixo ajudam no entendimento da minha pergunta. Tentei seguir um passo a passo pra criar um Custom Auth, mas me perdi na sequência e não consegui entrar em contato com quem teve a mesma dúvida que eu. :(

Link 1: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41154660/laravel-auth-external-data-for-login-and-register?rq=1

Link 2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38104647/laravel-authentication-via-external-api

Comment: Node + Framework Laravel ? é isso !!!!!!!!!! ???

Comment: Web Service em Node e o Web Site em Laravel. É uma má ideia?

Comment: não, é que sua pergunta não tem um foco especifico, está um pouco confuso!

Comment: Beleza! Vou editar e tentar deixar um pouco melhor o entendimento ;)

Comment: Cara só me esclarece uma coisa, na sua aplicação em laravel vai consumir todas as informações do seu Webservices em node? ou na sua aplicação também vai ter um database?

Comment: @KayoBruno Vai ser tudo consumido do Webservice!

Comment: @gViegas Você terá que criar um custom authenication driver, com isso você vai poder usar os métodos do Auth. Na documentação do laravel tem exemplos de como você pode fazer.